# When do I need to call requestAnimationFrame()?

Tags: javascript, css, performance, requestanimationframe

I do understand that [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) is very helpful when running animations that constantly change a style property over time.

```
const e = document.getElementById('e');
let count = 0;

function move(timestamp) {
  e.style.left = ++count + 'px';
  requestAnimationFrame(move);
};

requestAnimationFrame(move);
```

---

Now my question is: *Does it make sense to wrap everything that changes the visual appearance of the view in `requestAnimationFrame`?*

In other words, will this *pseudocode* example have a better performance than without `requestAnimationFrame`?

```
const e = document.getElementById('e');
let f = document.createDocumentFragment();

nodes.forEach((node, index) => {
    f.appendChild(node);
}

requestAnimationFrame(timestamp => {
    e.classList.toggle('active');
    container.classList.add('active');
    container.appendChild(fragment);
});
```

Comment: I wouldn't use it like that. `requestAnimationFrame` is *very* useful when you need a loop, like when using `canvas` or when animating a CSS property like `transform` or `opacity`.

Comment: No, it does not make sense to put all dom updates in a rAF callback. It's used for 60s fps timing. if you're not animating, there's usually no point to using rAF. It's unclear what you're comparing in your question though.

Comment: @AndyRay Thanks for your feedback. I've updated the example to make my point clearer – hopefully. When performing updates on multiple DOM elements but only once in a while (e.g. `onclick`), is it better to use `requestAnimationFrame()` or does the browser optimize all updates itself?

Comment: You don't need `requestAnimationFrame` for _"only once in a while."_ Especially for a few DOM updates. They should all be repainted in the same/next frame.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is *"use requestAnimationFrame (rAF) for frequent updates"*. This mostly involves animations or making DOM modifications during scroll/resize. If you're just doing a one-off DOM mutation, you can generally just do it and move on. It doesn't ever hurt to use rAF though, especially if you're not sure if there are other DOM mutations taking place on the page.

If you are doing a lot of DOM heavy updates, there are libraries out there which take care of this in a responsible and performant way (Greensock, React, Vue, many others).

If you're writing by hand, you should understand how browsers calculate layout and queue paint cycles. You also need to understand how JavaScript interacts with the render engine. For example, there's a [bunch of element properties](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a) which cause a reflow simply by reading the property. These are expensive operations and should the carefully managed.